# IPA file size Flash Builder export

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, flash-builder

i'm going to build an IOS app for the IPad, and i made a quick test.api. My issue is that the size of the file is already 13 MB big. i added a video and a sound for testing (together like 9 MB) so i was wondering is there a minimum file size when making a ipa in Flash Builder?

Maybe around 4 MB?

13MB - 9MB = 4 MB?

and then 4MB is the standard ipa size.

Answer (score 1):

Flex/AS3 mobile apps must include the SDK in  the output in order to run.  It is referred to as "Captive Runtime" and is an option on Android, but mandatory on iOS. Essentially, they are native apps that run as virtual machines that allow you to display your AS3/Flex apps on the device without a hint of Objective-C or Java. Those SDKs are far from small. If you look in %FlashBuilder Install Directory%/sdks/, you'll see that those SDKs can be close to 1GB in size. Obviously, that doesn't all get included, but from my experience, the smallest IPA I have ever created was around 8MB.

I don't have a solid answer for what the absolute minimum size of those SDKs are, and Google turned up nothing, but my guess would be somewhere between 4-8MB, depending on if you used Flex or not.

Comment: Although the essence of your answer is right, you're confusing a SDK with a runtime here. The SDK is not getting packaged with the app and deployed to the device, the runtime is. Two pairs of shoes really.

Comment: i found someting that claims to calculate the size of your IPA, ive tried but it didnt come close to my file size, URL:http://www.indiepinion.com/steffenj/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-iphone-app-after-approval/ i appreciate your awnser and i think some files are included but i dont think that is causing the big file.

Comment: @Al_Birdy I was just going off of experience with the Android apps. My app without Captive Runtime is ~2MB. With Captive Runtime, it is up at 9-10MB. And yes, I believe you are right. Packaging the SDK makes no sense now that I think about it. It's overkill. You just need the component that reads and executes the code.